# xcode AVAudioRecorder How to perform a background record every 30 minutes

Tags: xcode, avaudiorecorder

I have recording working while the app is in the background (added audio to background modes), it will record indefinitely and the app remains active while in the background.

I would like to be able to have the app remain active in the background and record a 30 second sound clip say every 30 minutes.

I have tried using `NSTimer` in conjunction with `AVAudioRecorder`'s `recordForDuration:` method but the app is killed off before `NSTimer` can fire. Any ideas?

The following code works in the background and records for 5 seconds every 5 seconds but if I increase scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval to 1 minute it doesn't work.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];



    // retrieve avaudiosession instance
    _session = [ AVAudioSession sharedInstance];
    // set category
    NSError *errRet;
    [_session setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayAndRecord error:&errRet];
    [_session setActive:YES error:&errRet];


    NSArray *dirPaths;
    NSString *docsDir;

    dirPaths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(
                                                   NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    docsDir = dirPaths[0];

    NSString *soundFilePath = [docsDir
                               stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"sound.caf"];

    NSURL *soundFileURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:soundFilePath];

    NSDictionary *recordSettings = [NSDictionary
                                    dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                    [NSNumber numberWithInt:AVAudioQualityMin],
                                    AVEncoderAudioQualityKey,
                                    [NSNumber numberWithInt:16],
                                    AVEncoderBitRateKey,
                                    [NSNumber numberWithInt: 2],
                                    AVNumberOfChannelsKey,
                                    [NSNumber numberWithFloat:44100.0],
                                    AVSampleRateKey,
                                    nil];

    NSError *error = nil;

    _audioRecorder = [[AVAudioRecorder alloc]
                      initWithURL:soundFileURL
                      settings:recordSettings
                      error:&error];

    if (error)
    {
        NSLog(@"error: %@", [error localizedDescription]);
    } else {
        [self recordAudio];
        NSTimer* timer;
        timer=[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval: 10.0 target:self selector:@selector(recordAudio) userInfo:nil repeats: YES];
        NSLog(@"timer fired");
    }
}


- (IBAction)recordAudio{

    if (!_audioRecorder.recording)
    {
        NSError *errRet;
        [_session setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryRecord error:&errRet];
        [_session setActive:YES error:&errRet];
        //_play.enabled = NO;
        [_audioRecorder recordForDuration:5.0];
        NSLog(@"Finished Recording");
    }
}
```

Comment: Please include some of your source code inside your question.

Comment: This works starting a record every 10 seconds for a duration of 5 seconds, if I increase the scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval to 60 seconds it doesn't work while in the background.

Comment: i'm facing the same question too. Have you got it done and how it works?

Comment: do you want NSTimer run in background ? modify code to  

[[UIApplication sharedApplication] beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler:nil];

timer=[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval: 10.0 target:self selector:@selector(recordAudio) userInfo:nil repeats: YES];

[[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] addTimer:loop forMode:NSRunLoopCommonModes];

Answer (score 0):

Skype does this so you can also.

You need to set UIBackgroundModesaudio in Info.plist, and you need to make sure that the audio session is active/running/whatever before you switch apps (the assumption is that you won't suddenly start recording/playing music/whatever when your app is in the background).

The docs say that "audio" lets you play audio in the background, but presumably this also applies to recording audio. If it doesn't work, there are a few things you could try:

- Set both "voip" and "audio".
- Play silence (this might be easiest to
  do with the Audio Queue API).

Comment: I read somewhere that apple will reject apps that set voip as background mode but don't actually use voip as part of core app functionality, I'll look at the play silence option, thanks.

Comment: For now dont use voip because you are not voip provider